# Disable Hyper-Threading on Dell XPS L502x

Tags: bios, dell-xps, hyper-threading

Does anyone know how, or if it's even possible, to disable Hyper-Threading on an Dell XPS L502x?

I've checked the BIOS, which seems like it's hiding a lot of the usual options, but can't see anything.

I've tried disabling Intel SpeedStep, which did nothing.

Thanks
Kieron

Comment: Why disable it?

Comment: Because the nature of the apps I run means I'd rather have them run with 25% of the available CPU than 12% (they're primarily single threaded for a lot of the operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that via a mod-ed BIOS, see this [thread](http://forum.notebookreview.com/dell-xps-studio-xps/635536-l502x-modded-bioses-download-gpu-voltages-more.html).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS.

On FreeBSD `sysctl machdep.hyperthreading_allowed=0` will disable it.

According to [these similar posts on superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/305887/disable-hyperthreading-in-the-windows-7-registry) it might be a bit harder on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

check this modded bios it might solve your issues

http://forum.notebookreview.com/dell-xps-studio-xps/635536-l502x-modded-bioses-download-gpu-voltages-more.html