# Disable hyper-threading via BIOS? in Ubuntu

Tags: bios, multi-threaded

I bought new Lenovo Ideapad 700, 6th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ Processor (2.60GHz 6MB),

I need to disable hyper-threading via BIOS for my Ubuntu, but I could not find where it is, on the older and most of the available Desktops, it is fast-forwarded?!

Thanks :)

Comment: You can't disable "multi-threading". Do you mean Hyper-Threading?  This smell of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) though... Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: yes sorry I mean hyperthreading.

Comment: I wanna to disable it because I want to make the test with/without hyperthreading and compare the results!!

Comment: @Mahdi - If there isn't an option in the BIOS then I am 99.99% sure it cannot be done.  What problem are you trying to solve, **edit your question**, by disabling Hyper-Threading?

Comment: @Mahdi Can you show us an image of your BIOS if possible?

Comment: "I wanna to disable it because I want to make the test with/without hyperthreading and compare the results" - Set the affinity of the process to only use the number of cores you want used.

Comment: [Disable Hyperthreading in the Windows 7 registry](http://superuser.com/questions/305887/disable-hyperthreading-in-the-windows-7-registry)

Comment: [disable hyperthreading on a multi-core Dell PC](http://superuser.com/questions/505820/disable-hyperthreading-on-a-multi-core-dell-pc?rq=1), which basically indicates, unless there is an option and setting the affinity isn't an accetpable solution, you are simply out of luck.  Related: [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/505820/disable-hyperthreading-on-a-multi-core-dell-pc?rq=1)

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu, as you may know disabling joint core similar to disabling HT but it is not exactly the same. On the other machine when I disabled HT instead of 8 lcore I just see 4 cores.

Comment: @Ramhound
you mean by setting GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash isolcpus=C0,C1,.." Or disabling HT the results should be the same?!

Comment: Yes?  But unless you replace the bios firmware your limited by the functionality of your OEM hardware