# Disable hyperthreading on Vivobook 15

Tags: windows-10, gaming, hyper-threading, amd-ryzen

**Updated:** I've already done this thing before write this post.
[Disable Hyperthreading in the Windows 7 registry](https://superuser.com/questions/305887/disable-hyperthreading-in-the-windows-7-registry)
I'd searching many many threads about this problem, no answer, so I ask for further information. I don't understand why someone still vote down my question after I edited.

Sorry for my bad English.

**Specs:**
My problem laptop:
- Asus Vivobook X512DA A512DA (a laptop).
- AMD Ryzen R5 3500U with Vega 8.
- 8GB of physical ram (but 6GB usable because of the iGPU).
- SSD 500GB.
My another laptop and perform as expected:
- HP Elite Book (another laptop).
- Intel i7 8550U with Intel UHD 620.
- 16GB of physical ram.
- SSD 500GB.

**Problem:**
- The Ryzen 3500U with Vega 8 just gets 40-45fps in game *League of Legend* (lowest setting 1080p) but 60-80 fps in game *Dota 2* (medium setting 1080p).
- The CPU keep running at **1400MHz**, instead of running at **2100 - 3700MHz** like it when it was working (processing data, rendering, etc).
- In gaming, the **temperature** is **always below 60** C degree.
- In other hand, the Intel i7 8550U gets 60-70fps in game *League of Legend* (highest setting, low shadow) but 50-60fps in game *Dota 2* (lowest setting 1080p, even lower than the ryzen).

[image: highest setting]
[image: lowest setting]

**What I believe in:**
- This League of Legend game only use 2 threads (what it want is more Hz per core). So if I want to **get more fps in game *League of Legend***, I've to disable SMT (hyper threading) to force the cpu focus on the main thread per core.

**What I've done:**
- I know that disable HT (or SMT) is bios feature only, but the cheap laptop Vivobook X512DA A512DA does not allow that (it does not have that option in bios setting).
- I've downloaded some software like cpu packer, unpacker... but I've not seen anythink like pack a core (or a thread), it lacks many features compared to the preview images in the web, it only has reduce all to 5% 10% or something I dont really understand. msconfig seem not helping much when setting cores to 2 will make cpu only use 2 threads in 1 core.

**What I hope:**
- May there are some tricks to get 60fps for the game, or something like disable the second thread per core.

**Thank you all.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Hyperthreading in the Windows 7 registry](https://superuser.com/questions/305887/disable-hyperthreading-in-the-windows-7-registry)

Comment: No it not solved my problem.

Comment: How can you have a Ryzen with an Intel GPU?

Comment: I have 2 laptops, one is Vivobook 15 ryzen 3500U, one is HP Elitebook intel 8550U

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You have extremely different hardware.

Comment: Sorry. My question is disable Hyperthreading on Vivobook 15 (ryzen 3500U)

Comment: If there is no option in the bios/uefi, then you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The Vivobook does not make this option available in the BIOS, the location such an option would typically be made available.

So, absent writing a custom BIOS firmware (good luck), you cannot disable hyperthreading on the Vivobook 15.